# Question regarding trigonometry

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I've got this thing on my mind : we know that $cos(x)$ is a periodic function , hence integral from $2(k-1) \pi$ to $2k  \pi$ will yield the same value for any $k \geq1$.

My question is , why is this integral property  still true when considering $ \cos^{n} (x)$ ? Intuitively , it seems right , but I would be much more comfortable with a rigorous explanation .

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: $\cos^{n} (x + 2\pi) = \cos^{n} (x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Panda Bear notes in a comment, since $\cos(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, we have $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x)$ for any value of $x$.  Thus, $\cos^n(x+2\pi)=\cos^n(x)$ for any value of $x$ and $\cos^n(x)$ is also periodic with period $2\pi$.